# Run .bat file from Visual Studio Code debugger similar to Code Runner Extension

Tags: python, batch-file, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

In my work environment pycharm is used as an IDE to run a specifically configured batch file which sets up the python Interpreter. It also includes special modules that I otherwise cannot use (the code fails at `import special_stuff as foo`)

Via the Code Runner Extension I am able to simply run my code via the same .bat file (it is also possible when I select the default Interpreter properly. However, I can not use formatting then, as it is not present in the "work"-python configuration)

The setting.json for the code Runner looks like this:

```
"Code-Runner.executorMap": {
  "python": "C:\\folder\\special_stupid_python.bat",
}
```

The code execution looks like the following then in the terminal

`C:\folder\special_stupid_python.bat "d:\project\some_script.py"`

**I face two issues:**

I now want to debug files with the vscode debugger. However, I am not able to figure out how to debug the file in context of the debugger. I tried tinkering around with the launch.json and task.json files. Unfortunately, without much success.

Additionally, I get no linter indication/ type hints for the specific module (i.e. when typing `module.` I get not recommendations on methods and objects) despite having the modules added to extraPaths in the settings.json

Comment: For the first question, what is "how to debug the file in context of the debugger" in detail? Whether the breakpoint is valid.  For the second question, this is the intelligent prompt of pylance extension. Can you provide the relevant code and your settings.json, to reproduce the problem? I am not sure if this is a bug or your setup problem